# this.* not working with async/await javascript (node 8.6.0)

Tags: node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I couldn't find why I get this error:

[image]

And here is my code:

```js
  create: async (data) => {
    const insertedData = await dbProvider.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', data);
    console.log(this);
    return await this.getById(insertedData.insertId);
  },
  getById: async (id) => {
    const data = await dbProvider.query('SELECT * From users WHERE id = ?', id);
    return data;
  },
```

Create gets called with await repo.create(data);
the create calls this.getById which results in an error.
Any idea why this happens?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async`/`await` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Because arrow functions are *pre-bound* to the lexical `this`.

If you want a dynamic `this` inside of a function, it cannot be an arrow function:

```
  async create(data) {
    const insertedData = await dbProvider.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', data);
    console.log(this);
    return await this.getById(insertedData.insertId);
  },
  async getById(id) {
    const data = await dbProvider.query('SELECT * From users WHERE id = ?', id);
    return data;
  },
```